# How can I say following sentences properly? ''He drinks water at once ''

Tags: word-choice

- The meaning is, drinking water in one gulp.

Comment: What is wrong with that gulp? *at once* would not properly express what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say "He drinks the water in one gulp"

Casually "He downs" or "He chugs" the water